# Get value from input type which is append in table in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an issue to get a value from input box. This input type is used in a table td in javaScript code. The code looks like:

```
var markup = "<tr id ='row"+idd+"' class info'>";
 markup += "<td>"+select box text+"<input class='test' name='example["+id+"][name]'
type='hidden' value='"+select box option value+"'></td>";

$("table tbody").append(markup);
```

now I want to get the value of input type. How can I get? Please help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are generating markup, give input a class, say `class="desiredinput"`

Now to fetch its value, do:

```
$(".desiredinput").val();
```

Comment: @HemantSingh you should accept correct answer. In future your question and it's answer will helpful to other users

Answer (score 0):

Add `id` attribute in `input` tag like this `id="inputTypeID"`

then you can get it's value using `JQuery` (Make sure you have included `JQuery` library)

```
 $("#inputTypeID").val();
```

and without `JQuery`:

```
document.getElementById("inputTypeID").value;
```